# stringByAppendingString gives unpredictable results

Tags: objective-c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

Newbie Question - but much in need of an answer...In this loop, the string variable lineString sometimes will be null and sometimes will have additional garbage characters appended to the end of it. I would greatly appreciate if someone would be able to explain why this is happening....Thanks in Advance:

```
NSMutableArray* lineStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];
NSMutableArray *linestoJoin = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 0;
for (NSString *currentLine in lineStrings) {
        NSArray *arr = [currentLine componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *TSN = (NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *speciesName = (NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:1];
   //This stringByAppendingString sometimes results in added garbage or nothing at all!!
        NSString *lineString = [[speciesName stringByAppendingString:@"," ] stringByAppendingString:TSN];
        [linestoJoin addObject:lineString];
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Try using `NSString *lineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", speciesName, TSN];`. What does that give you?

Comment: BTW - no need for the `(NSString *)` casts. And try modern syntax: `NSString *TSN = arr[0];`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks very much!  the stringWithFormat: did the trick..Still not sure why stringByAppendingString didn't work - I've used a few times in similar situations with no trouble!